# Generate CSS from existing Sprite Image

Tags: css, sprite, css-sprites

I know there are tools to generate a sprite image and CSS from a collection of images.

But, is there a way to generate the CSS against an existing sprite image.
I was given a sprite image as-is with no CSS and am looking for a way to auto-generate the CSS instead of having to hand code it.

Answer (score 0):

Like: 
http://www.spritecow.com/ ?
http://www.spritebox.net/ ?
A simple Google search shows a lot of sites that will help you with this.